# How can I enable the developer console on a non-US keyboard?

Tags: portal-2, keyboard

I tried to enable the developer console in the options menu in Portal 2, but it doesn't work out of the box because I'm using a German keyboard and the <kbd>~</kbd> key is not recognized.

I tried to edit the `config.cfg` and replace the keybinding from <kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>\</kbd>, but my changes are reset when I start Portal 2 again. How can I permanently change the keybinding for the developer console?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do the following, just tested, steps:

1. Add the parameter `-console` to Launch Settings of Portal 2.
2. Launch Portal 2 (developer console should be already there).
3. Write and execute in console: `bind f11 toggleconsole`
4. Test that pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> toggles the console.
5. Now exit Portal 2 and relaunch it. Everything should work as expected.

Comment: u must to write "" for the button u want to use for console and for the command of the button. in this case "F11" "toggleconsole" try now and u have your console when u want =) sorry for my english, i'm italian.

Answer (score 0):

Create `autoexec.cfg` in your `cfg` folder, with the contents:

> bind \ toggleconsole

If this file does not automatically execute, try putting `+exec autoexec.cfg` in your launch options.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I noticed that the `config.cfg` has the command `unbindall` at the very beginning, depending on the order the files are loaded that might reset my changes in the `autoexec.cfg`

Comment: You can however put the bind command in the config.cfg though.  It's not recommended but it is possible.