# Can you reset your Portal 2 coop progress?

Tags: portal-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you reset saved multiplayer progress in Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20459/how-do-you-reset-saved-multiplayer-progress-in-portal-2)

GLaDOS mentions a few lines as you and your cooperative testing partner in science unlock areas. Once you progress past a stage, those lines are never again played. If you play with somebody who has full access, you never hear any.

Is it possible to reset one's coop progress?

Comment: It doesn't sucks. It's really a non-issue in my opinion since there is so little storyline in the coop mode. But if you want to hear all her comments, you can watch these videos: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwYSxnV0ycU http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4bE9uyru4k http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rINE2tQrcvg

Comment: @eric Thanks for that. Can you please post that as an answer to the other question? lt'd be awesome.

Comment: badp: Done.